# Одна колонка сильно больше остальных в графике

Tags: highcharts

Одна колонка сильно длиннее остальных. 
Можно ли каким либо способом её обрезать средствами highcharts (вставить многоточие например)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прологарифмируйте все данные

Comment: Либо используйте `type: 'logarithmic'` ось

Comment: Логарифмирование выглядит не очень внешне. Столбец наполовину больше но в одном значение 30 а в другом 300, что в 10 раз больше а не в 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение. называется breaks. Добавляется в yAxis и xAxis.

Еще надо подключить [файл](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/broken-axis.js) с этим модулем, иначе работать не будет. 
Чтобы был виден разрыв столбца, используется специальная функция pointBreakColumn которую можно найти в примере.

```
yAxis: {
           breaks: [{ 
                from: 200,
                to: 1500,
           }]
}
```

Пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/ppotaczek/txof86a4/1/

Доки:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.breaks